# Mach-O linker error when building

Tags: clang, linker-errors

I get a Mach-O Linker error when I try to build my app.

> ld: 9 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting derived data solved it

Answer (score 0):

You might have two copies of the same file.  Delete one. Check in compile sources under the build phase. You should be able to find a duplicated file.

Comment: I don't have a duplicate file.

Comment: Common reasons for this error are duplicated files (usually main), or multiple interfaces with the same name, and lastly check in your code if you have any *.m imports, .m import will give a Mach-O Linker error.